# How to compare multiple rows that have duplicates in all columns but one, and display the different column, in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a few days now. Anything I try returns unwanted results.

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is compare rows from the same table. Let's say this is the table in question:

```
name  |  hobby
------+------------
Bill  |  fishing     <- 1
Bill  |  basketball  <- 2
Bill  |  tennis      <- 3
Peter |  soccer
Peter |  baseball
Joe   |  tennis      <- 3
Joe   |  basketball  <- 2
Peter |  fishing
Dave  |  tennis
Joe   |  fishing     <- 1
Dave  |  fishing
Dave  |  basketball
Dave  |  football
```

What I want to have my query return, is a table that shows the names of two people that have exactly the same hobbies, and the amount of hobbies they have in common. It must not display the same name twice in one row. If we were to execute the query on this table, the result would be:

```
name1   |   name2   |   nr_of_hobbies
--------+-----------+----------------
Bill    |   Joe     |   3
Joe     |   Bill    |   3
```

I've tried all kinds of queries, using joins, subqueries, a mix thereof, but I just haven't been able to hit the nail on its head. I'm especially having a hard time figuring out how to compare multiple items from one column, where items from other columns are the same. Any help would we greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM mytable AS t
       WHERE t.name = t1.name) AS t1_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM mytable AS t
       WHERE t.name = t2.name) AS t2_count        
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.hobby = t2.hobby 
WHERE t1.name <> t2.name
GROUP BY t1.name, t2.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = t1_count AND COUNT(*) = t2_count
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b9ed/3)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos. This was exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @7z.  . . . I am failing to see how this is the answer you are looking for.  Your specified answer has three columns -- for instance -- and this has four.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that's correct, but that's not the crux of what I was looking to do. I primarily wanted to understand how to do a search for multiple values in one column, for which values in another column are the same. Your answer was helpful as well, but I myself had never used or even heard of group_concat before. It was thus helpful in the sense that you expanded my horizon as to what I can achieve with SQL, but it didn't make things as intuitive as Giorgos' answer did. Hence I chose his answer.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, the easiest way is to use `group_concat()`.  Note:  this puts the names in the same column:

```
select group_concat(name) as names, hobbies
from (select name, group_concat(hobby order by hobby) as hobbies
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
group by hobbies
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can do the same thing with `join` if you want pairs:

```
select n1.name as name1, n2.name as name2
from (select name, group_concat(hobby order by hobby) as hobbies
      from t
      group by name
     ) n1 join
     (select name, group_concat(hobby order by hobby) as hobbies
      from t
      group by name
     ) n2
     on n1.hobbies = n2.hobbies and n1.name <> n2.name;
```

Comment: I would add n1.name<>n2.name in the join condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will definitely keep this method in mind. I've chosen the other answer as the solution, because I primarily wanted to understand which subqueries I had to involve to search through multiple rows. Notwithstanding, great answer.